# Number of tags per page and spamming

Tags: seo, tags

What is the suggested ratio of `<strong>` and `<em>` to text? Lets say I have 100 words, is putting 20 of them in a `<strong>` tag considered ok?

Example:

> Lorem ipsum **aaa** dolor sit amet, consectetur **aaa** adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim **aaa** ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut **aaa** aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor **aaa** in reprehenderit in voluptate **aaa** velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non **aaa** proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt **aaa** mollit anim id est laborum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such ratio... You should use strong, em and i as much as it makes sense too use it.

Answer (score 1):

It was said that one point search engines added weight to terms that were bold or in italics. This was quite a few years ago. This proved to be a flawed concept and search engines no longer look for this kind of markup (if they ever really did).

Use your markup as you wish but do not over do it thinking that it helps SEO. It doesn't. Be natural in your content and markup and you will always be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such ratio of  and  to use per page. But, you should use the  and  tags in such a way that the content looks attractive (not spamming).

We look at five mistakes that can be easily avoided when designing your site with SEO in mind.

- Code your pages semantically, using unique and descriptive meta and heading tags, containing well-researched conversion-focused keywords. Remember not to stuff your pages with keywords though, as Google will regard this as spamming!
- Keep your site structure shallow and make your content accessible within three clicks.
- Compress your images, use descriptive file names and use CSS3 effects where possible to minimize reliance on images.
- Avoid duplicate content issues with canonical tags.
- Ensure you have mobile versions of all your pages.